# passing variable to a string in a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to pass a variable into a string like this.

```
HTTParty.get(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false)
```

This works fine as a string, but I cant seem to get the syntax correct to make the parameters variables. Can someone please help me with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what issue you're having (or if the missing quotes are just a typo). Normal string interpolation should do what you want:

```
bar = "123.45"
plugh = "xyz"
HTTPart.get("blahblah?foo=#{bar}&baz=#{plugh}")
```

You'll want to url-encode the values as well, most likely, unless they're under control.

Comment: Unfortunately i get a bad uri error. the syntax above keeps everything as text and doesn't convert the variables into the proper string - here is the error I received -  bad URI(is not URI?): https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=#{lnglat}&radius=#{thisradius}&types=#{thistype}

Comment: Sorry.  Figured it out.  Had to use double quotes instead of single quotes.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No sweat. Remember to upvote or accept answers when they're helpful; that's what keeps the site going! :)